# How to make http call from class in class library C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, quartz.net

I am writing `Job Scheduler` using `Quartz` library in `C#`. My requirement is if a business condition is met, I need to make a call to `Apple` server.

This is how my Scheduler looks like:-

```
public class CustomerJob : BaseJob
{
    private readonly ICustomerSchedulerService _customerSchedulerService;

    public CustomerJob (ICustomerSchedulerService customerSchedulerService)
    {
        _customerSchedulerService= customerSchedulerService;
    }
    public override void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
       var customers = _customerSchedulerService.CheckExpiredTask();
       foreach(var customer in customers)
       {
           //I need to make a post request to apple server for each customer
           //something like below however there is no HttpClient() available in this class
        //var client = new HttpClient();      
       //client.PostAsync("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", customer));
       }
        base.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

So how to address this requirement??

Note:-
*I would not prefer to move this into API or Web based project, since this scheduler will be called from Web & API team & other(s).*

Thanks.

Comment: If HttpClient is not available, then make sure you're referenced the proper class library and have the correct `using namespace` statement at the top of your class. Calling a service from a class library makes no difference from calling it from any other place.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not available in your class, chances are you just need to add a reference at the top or change your line a little.

Replace `new HttpClient();` with `new  System.Net.Http.HttpClient();`. This should either work or Visual Studio (if that's what you're using) should tell you potential fixes :)

Hope this helps, if not reply and I might be able to identify your next problem :)

Comment: Are you not able to add the nuget package for it?

Comment: I can get it from https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.http/. But are you sure is this right way to do?? Since I am not.. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the way most people would do it, all you are doing is adding a library, should be no problem.

Comment: Is this the only way to make a post request to server,?? any alternative or better way would be welcome.. :)

Comment: Is your class library a (portable) class lib?

Comment: No, normal class library

Comment: I'd suggest using the httpclient then, it's what Microsoft recommend

Comment: Okay. Cool then. Thanks. Upvoting your post for now. Will mark accepted later some day. Waiting for some more inputs. Please upvote my post if you find it worth